# Can I use javascript automation on Windows?

Tags: javascript, windows, automation, applescript

I want to do some automation of iTunes on Windows. My javascript code works as I need it to on Mac using the Script Editor, but I don't know if that same code will work on Windows, and if so, what application I use instead of Apple's Script Editor to run it.

```
var itunes = Application('iTunes');
iTunes.play();
```

I've tried Javascript studio, and a few other editors but I don't seem to be able to get it to work – I'm new to JS, I'm familiar to AppleScript...

Comment: JS was originally created to run in a browser.

Comment: @PM77-1 While true, that's not really relevant.  Windows Script Host has supported JScript for a long time, and other JS implementations have been supported for a while as well

Answer (score 1):

You can use cscript or wscript (Windows Script Host, console or windowed) to launch javascript files.

There is also AutoIT and AuthoHotKey which are more self contained solutions for scripting Windows.

Another option is Visual Basic.

There is no AppleScript for Windows, I think the closest you will get is AutoIT.

Comment: That seems to just run a .js file, right? Is there something which is more of an equivalent Apple's Script Editor?

Comment: You are correct, cscript just runs a js file. I will expand the answer to include some more options for automating stuff on windows.

Comment: I still can't seem to get it to run. I save the code (excactly as above) as a .js file in an editor like Notepad++ and then try and run the file with cscript or wscript and neither works (nothing happens with cscript, and wscript says the file cannot be associated with it). What am I doing wrong?

I have used AutoIT, but just fear it's a little decrepit to make it easy for me to access the more niche features (e.g. multiple airplay devices) that I need access to.

Comment: It won't translate directly from the Mac script I'm afraid. I suggest getting some pre-made iTunes scripts for Windows and tweaking them for your needs.